# Not able to handle windows Authentication popup with selenium testNg and chrome driver

Tags: java, selenium

i tried to do it with robot class and also tried with http://username:password@url but after opening the site links are not clickable any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Finally my issue got resolved .
issue with my situation is while navigation i used to switch in between http and https page and for https page basic authentication was set ,so at the stat of any script execution i have to first call http and then https page
1.http://username:password@www.google.com

2.https://username:password@www.google.com

by this through the execution i dont need to give basic auth anywhere